# slider to change gis data

Tags: gis, netlogo

I currently have a dataset consisting of four shp files - minimum temperature, maximum temperature, mean temperature and precipitation - for each coordinate of the file. The problem I'm trying to solve demands that I should be able to dynamically change these variables while running the model. I was thinking of using a slider but I'm not sure if it is possible to use a slider to change shapefile values and I also did a little research on the web and haven't found anyone trying to solve this issue. 
Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to select which variable to use, or are you wanting to change the value of whichever variable you are using in some way (eg reduce the precipitation by 10% for all patches)?

Comment: I've four different variables and I would like to create a slider for each one and be able to change them as you said p.e. reduce 10% of precipitation/maxtemperature/whatever for all patches. I already assigned each variable from the gis file to each patch. What I don't know is if I can change the patches variables because they're read from the file

Comment: Change data (like the title of the question), or just the visualization? Do you change also the shapes of figures or only the attribute? What do you want at the end? (a new shapefile, something to visualize something, something to import in gis, something to work with)

Comment: The goal is to test the behaviour of the agents according to environmental changes. I don't need to export/change the gis file. I just need to change the the attributes' values while running the model to see how that will affect the agents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so in your `setup` code, you have something that reads in the GIS data and assigns four attributes for each patch. Assume those variables are called min-temp, max-temp, mean-temp and precipitation. So you have some code like this at the top:

```
patches-own
[ min-temp
  max-temp
  mean-temp
  precipitation
]
```

You can create extra variables - so replace that with something like:

```
patches-own
[ min-temp-GIS
  max-temp-GIS
  mean-temp-GIS
  precipitation-GIS
  min-temp
  max-temp
  mean-temp
  precipitation
]
```

Assign the values from the GIS dataset to the first four variables. Create your sliders (eg max-temp-factor) and add the following to your setup code.

```
to setup
  ... <all the code to import the values>
  ask patches
  [ set max-temp max-temp-GIS * max-temp-factor
    ... <same for other three variables>
  ]
  ...
end
```

Now the patches have two values and your slider is simply a multiplier (or can go from -10 to +10 and adds to the temperature etc) so that you can have scenarios like 'what if there is a 20% lower precipitation' or 'what if max temperature was 10 degrees higher'. Your default values on the sliders would be 0 for the 'addition' factors and 1 for the 'multiplier' factors.

If you want to change the values during the simulation (so the first year has normal temperature but then it goes up), then you will need to do the `ask patches [set max-temp max-temp-GIS * max-temp-factor]` code in the beginning of the `go` step so that it calculates these variables each `tick`.